# How to get a string from http request in swift

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, nsurl

I'm supposed to make an http call to a url, and it will return either "Invalid" or "Valid" depending on what I have at the end of the url. I can't figure out how to do it, though. I'm very new to http and am not entirely sure how it works. But I've got this far:

```
func httpcall(urlbit: String) {
    var urlor = "http://notrealurl.com/etix.asp?t=scanticket&sid=100000&tid="
    urlor += urlbit

    let url = NSURL(string: urlor)

    let task = NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithURL(url!) {(data, response, error) in
        var feedback = (NSString(data: data, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding))
    }

    task.resume()

    if feedback == "invalid" {
        return false
    } else if feedback == "valid" {
        return true
    }
}
```

Obviously, this isn't working. Expecting feedback to return anything is obviously ridiculous. I just need to figure out how to access whatever data it obtains from calling the url - more specifically, though, I need to get the string that this server is supposed to send me.

EDIT: Okay, so I learned a bit more about NSURL and I think I have something that is nearly coherent. It still doesn't work, but I believe I'm getting close. Here's my code:

```
func httpcall2(urlbit: String, onResult: (Bool)-> Void) {
    var urlor = "http://notreal.com/etix.asp?t=scanticket&sid=100000&tid="
    urlor += urlbit

    let url = NSURL(string: urlor)

    let task = NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithURL(url!) {(data, response, error) in
        var feedback = (NSString(data: data, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)) as String!
        onResult(response=="Invalid")
    }

    task.resume()
}
```

And here's what I use to call the function

```
httpcall2(mystr, { (responseWasInvalid: Bool) in
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), { () -> Void in
    if responseWasInvalid == true {
        self.messageLabel.text = "valid"
    } else if responseWasInvalid == false {
        self.messageLabel.text = "invalid"
    }

    })
})
```

It still doesn't seem to actually receive anything from calling the url.

Comment: To enter text as code, indent the line with 4 spaces. There are guidelines for posting you may want to look at.

Answer (score 0):

Put the if else check inside the closure. Your current code does not make sense because you are checking the response before the response is available

**Update**

A solution could be something like this:

```
func networkFunction(query: String, completion: (success: Bool) -> Void) {
    var url = "http://notrealurl.com/etix.asp?t=scanticket&sid=100000&tid=" + query

    let task = NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithURL(NSURL(string: url)!, completionHandler: { (responseData, response, error) -> Void in
        if error == nil {
            let feedback = NSString(data: responseData, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)

            completion(success: feedback == "valid")
        } else {
            println(error)
            completion(success: false)
        }
    })
}

networkFunction("what ever", { (success) -> Void in
    println(success)
    /* if you want to update the UI have to do it on the main thread:
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), { () -> Void in
        view.backgroundColor = .redColor()
    })
    */
})
```

Please read about Closures in general to get an idea about what it is and how to use it

Comment: okay, so I edited a bit more. http://pastebin.com/43PPsiKG but now it says,"use of unresolved identifier,'returnstate'". How do I fix this issue?

Comment: okay, so it turns out my function declares the variable returnstate and returns it before the http call can get a chance to edit it. Do you have any ideas for how to fix this?

Comment: This works for me, but I dont know how to store the contents of "prntln" in a string!  let url = NSURL(string: "http://cloud.com/motova-1/?viewname=STANDARDJSON&userinput="+txtuserinput.text)
        let request = NSURLRequest(URL: url!)
        NSURLConnection.sendAsynchronousRequest(request, queue: NSOperationQueue.mainQueue()) {
            (response, data, error) in
            println(NSString(data: data, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding))}